# Accessing value in multidimensional JSON array using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays, json

I would like to get values from JSON file and insert to html.

based on this JSON array I am trying to pull data insert to html tags using jquery and create page:

```
 $.getJSON( "/general.json", function( data ) {

var jarray = data;
for(i = 0; i <=jarray.length; i++){
  var project  = jarray[i].project;
  var fulltime = jarray[i].bars.fulltime.resource;
  var contractor = jarray[i].bars.contractor.resource;
  var vendor = jarray[i].bars.vendor.resource;
  var capacity = jarray[i].bars.contractor.resource;
  var dept = jarray[i].department;

  jarray.push('<div class = "projects" >');
  jarray.push('<div class = "project" >');
  jarray.push('<div class = "label" >"'+ project+'"</div>');
  jarray.push('<div class = "progress" >');
  jarray.push('<span class = "'+ fulltime +'" ></span>');
  jarray.push('<span class = "'+ contractor +'" ></span>');
  jarray.push('<span class = "'+ vendor +'" ></span>');
  jarray.push('<span class = "'+ capacity +'" ></span>');
  jarray.push('</div>');  
  jarray.push('</div>');  
  jarray.push('</div>');

}

  $('.projects').html(jarray.join('')).appendTo(".department_other  > h2");
```

});
but because the array is to complicated cant access desirable values. Would be appreciated any suggestion, thanks.

Comment: I have edited JSON structure and was trying implement @Pualo Roberto's suggested code but still cant make it work

Comment: if you used the structure of @PauloRoberto then you need to write `var jarray = data.jsonArray`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: name your JSON childs and the father, i have corrected your JSON, but i'll give you a hint use this site http://json.parser.online.fr/ to manipulate JSON and see how it is.

Second: NEVER use child names as numbers like you did with `{"0":{}}`,`{"1":{}}` etc.. ALWAYS use a name, or do not use anything, like i did, so you can access directly, otherwise you cannot.

Third: to be precise, first think about what do you want and separate it in groups, organizated, before creating the JSON.

```json
var j = {
            "jsonArray":[
              {
                      "project": "x2 Mobile",
                      "bars": {
                          "fulltime": {
                              "resource": "progress-bar red",
                              "amount": 2
                          },
                          "contractor": {
                              "resource": "progress-bar blue",
                              "amount": 1
                          }
                      },
                      "project": "x2 PC/Web",
                      "bars": {
                          "fulltime": {
                              "resource": "progress-bar red",
                              "amount": 1
                          },
                          "contractor": {
                              "resource": "progress-bar blue",
                              "amount": 1
                          }
                      },
                      "project": "x2 Global/STB",
                      "bars": {
                          "fulltime": {
                              "resource": "progress-bar red",
                              "amount": 11
                          },
                          "contractor": {
                              "resource": "progress-bar blue",
                              "amount": 3
                          }
                      },
                      "project": "x3 Mobile/Apps",
                      "bars": {
                          "fulltime": {
                              "resource": "progress-bar red",
                              "amount": 2
                          },
                          "contractor": {
                              "resource": "progress-bar blue",
                              "amount": 2
                          }
                      },

                  "department": "Herrin"
              },
              {
                      "project": "App Icon Strategy",
                      "bars": {
                          "fulltime": {
                              "resource": "progress-bar red",
                              "amount": 1
                          }
                      },
                  "department": "Herrin/Other"
              },
              {
                      "project": "Packaging",
                      "bars": {
                          "fulltime": {
                              "resource": "progress-bar red",
                              "amount": 1
                          }
                      },
                      "project": "Customer Journey",
                      "bars": {
                          "fulltime": {
                              "resource": "progress-bar red",
                              "amount": 1
                          },
                          "contractor": {
                              "resource": "progress-bar blue",
                              "amount": 1
                          },
                          "vendor": {
                              "resource": "progress-bar green",
                              "amount": 5
                          }
                      },
                  "department": "Other"
              }
          ]
};
```

Now you can access it by (for example, assuming that `i=0`):

```js
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
  var project  = j.jsonArray[i].project;
  var fulltime = j.jsonArray[i].bars.fulltime;
  var resource = j.jsonArray[i].bars.contractor.resource;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I think it's gonna work. I'll check and post my working code thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can access them in your loop with `val.bars.fulltime.resource` or `data[ i ].bars.fulltime.resource` for example.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout using underscore (http://underscorejs.org/) or lodash (http://lodash.com/). You could use uderscore's .pluck method to easily get at elements within your JSON object...

Comment: Jason object. Its yours!